# How to split the xml file using apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

l have a 20GB XML file in my local system, I want to split the data into multiple chunks and also I want to remove specific attributes from that file. how will I achieve using Nifi?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`SplitRecord`**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitRecord/index.html) processor and define [XML Reader](https://pierrevillard.com/2018/06/28/nifi-1-7-xml-reader-writer-and-forkrecord-processor/)/[Writer](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/199310/xml-record-writer-in-apache-nifi-170.html) controller services to read the xml data and write only the required attributes into your result xml.

Also define **`Records Per Split property`** value to include how many records you needed for each split.

Comment: Thank You, and also l want to convert the XML to CSV after splitting, for that do we need schema?

Comment: @Kum, in this case you need to define `XML reader`(with schema that matches your input data) and `CsvSetWriter` controller services and we need schema for `CsvSetWriter` only with the attributes that needed.